# left-div | center-div | right-div, everyone vertical-aligned

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to obtain this three-columns layout:

[image: my layout]

1. `div1` (green) with its content aligned **to the left**
2. `div2`  (blue) with its content aligned **to the center**
3. `div3` (magenta) with content its aligned **to the right**

Inside each column, I've multiple block element ("sheeps" in my mockup). Each element must be vertical-aligned to the "absolute" middle, no matter it's size: as the red-dotted line displays (more or less...), I need all the contained elements to have their **center on the same line**.

I'm starting from scratch, but **I cannot use any "fixed" dimensions**.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: My non-working crap is here http://jsfiddle.net/gV99f/6/

Comment: post you code in jsfiddle

Comment: have you considered using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think this is what you need. You need use tables or `display: table`, `display: table-cell`.

[JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q38jj/1)

Comment: Good idea, but I cannot use any "fixed" dimensions.

Comment: This method does not restrict thee fixed dimensions. See update http://jsfiddle.net/q38jj/1/  I wrote a fixed size for the demonstration

Comment: Your second one ended up for being exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use new property css3 `flex` like this :

HTML :

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="cyan"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#wrap{
    height:50px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:initial;
}
#wrap div{
    flex:1;
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/6cae7/1/**

And if you want adjust size you can use `flex-grow` property like this :

CSS :

```
#wrap{
    height:50px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:initial;
}
#wrap div{
    flex-grow:1;
}
#wrap div:nth-child(2){
    flex-grow:3;
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/6cae7/3/**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/54/)**.

Tried to make it, rest you can so same just by aligning

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"><span>div 1</span><br/><img src="http://i49.tinypic.com/bgd4qr.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a></div>
    <div class="center">div 2</div>
    <div class="right">div 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
}
.left {
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    background:magenta;
    float:left;
}
.left span{
      width:100px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.left img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;

}
.center {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.right {
    height:200px;
    width:150px;
    background:green;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/gV99f/9/)**

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <img src="http://www.w3.org/Style/Woolly/woolly-mc.png" width="100" height="100" />
    </div>
    <div class="aside aside-1">
        <img src="http://www.w3.org/Style/Woolly/woolly-mc.png" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="aside aside-2">
        <img src="http://www.w3.org/Style/Woolly/woolly-mc.png" width="150" height="150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.main {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
   padding: 100px 0;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 75px 0;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 2 0px;
  }

  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .main {
    order: 2;
  }

  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }

}
```